# "onfocus" event is not working for dynamically appended inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i'm appending inputs dynamically, onfocus function is not working.

My code

```
 $i=1;
<?php for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){?>
      <input type="text" onfocus="myFun(<?php echo $i?>)">
<?php}?>
```

My function is

```
function myFun(val){
      alert(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with using jQuery you could do like this. Dynamically added inputs will work this way with on focus.

```js
//******************************************************************
// JAVASCRIPT
//******************************************************************

// some function to do after focus.
// takes a value variable called val
function myFun(val){
  console.log(val);
}

// If you use the on method this way even if you
// add inputs after the DOM is loaded, then any 
// inputs with the class name "myInput" will 
// pass the focused value of the input to the myFun
// function above.
$("body").on("focus", ".myInput", function(){
  myFun($(this).val());
});
```

```html
//******************************************************************
// PHP
//******************************************************************
<?php
  for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
    echo "<input type='text' class='myInput' value='test value here => ".$i."'>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

cos all the inputs are the sames :( you need to add some

```
<?php 
 $i=1;
 for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){?>
      <input name="post_name[]" id="id_<?php echo $i?>" type="text" onfocus="myFun(<?php echo $i?>)">
<?php}?>
```

the javascript :

```
function myFun(val){
  alert(val);
}
```

Comment: How does name matter's with OP's question?

Comment: i think you talk about the class i just add name and this need username? initialized outside the class?